# Is there a way in R to count the number of unique statements in a string vector?

Tags: r, regex, string, tidyverse

I have a dataset that has comments. These comments contain important information. Inside each comment, the "//" represent a separation between statements. I would like to know how many statements I have in each comment. And I want to know how many unique statements I have in each comment as well. Is that possible? Thank you so much for your help. An example of data is below.

```
data<- structure(list(comment = c("Gary Goss made all notificiations and calls.  Plow and vehicle // PD remains and MoDOT crews remain on scene. // 646 en route to check status of incident. // 646  was sent to check on a camera incident involving a tractor trailer of potatoes that needed to be uprighted from earlier in the night. ", 
"Crash with a TT and a sedan into the guarrdail. // 1 vehicle only sedan into the guard rail. // Guard Rail Damage located via camera. // MSHP  C  160122961  TROOPER LACEY   // NEED TO ESTIMATE "
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 2):

We split the 'comment' column at the `//` (specify any zero or more spaces -`\\s*`) before or after the `//`), loop over the `list` with `lapply`, get the `unique` elements and get the `lengths` of the `list` of vectors

```
lengths(lapply(strsplit(trimws(data$comment), "\\s*//\\s*"), unique))
[1] 4 5
```

---

Or with `tidyverse` - create a sequence column before we split the 'comment' column with `separate_rows`, and then do a group by count of total number of rows (`n()`) and the count of unique elements (`n_distinct`) in 'comment' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
 mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
 separate_rows(comment, sep = "\\s*//\\s*") %>%
 group_by(rn) %>% 
 summarise(n = n(), unique_n = n_distinct(comment), .groups = 'drop')
```

Comment: Thanks, But can you please explain the code?

Comment: @MustafaKamal i updated the description

Comment: And to further clarify, as what you see is at times also what you don't see, the `trimws` removes any spaces before/after a comment that may have gotten embedded in the initial data capture, and `\\s*//\\s*` are internal. Or so I think. Really like the lengths/unique structure. Isn't `//` essentially acting as `\n`, though it doesn't matter as to solution.